# Calling a draw method from paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm working on a java homework assignment. The assignment is to take an array of 50 random integers and draw rectangles or lines whose height is the size of each member. When the JPanel is clicked selection sort will sort the array and repaint the rectangles, this time in order from smallest to largest. I have my drawPass method that is drawing all the rectangles. The assignment requires me to call the drawPass method from my paintComponent method. My problem is that I can't call my drawPass in paintComponent becuase drawPass needs to have a graphics object, but paintComponent doesn't have any parameters. Netbeans has underlined drawPass(); in my paintComponent method, and it says "required: Graphics, found: no arguments". Any help on how to call drawPass from paintComponent or any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
package hw10;

import static java.awt.Color.RED;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

/**
*
* @author tshade
*/
public class AnimatedSelectionSortPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    int[] numbers = new int[50];

    /**
     * Creates new form AnimatedSelectionSortPanel
     */
    public AnimatedSelectionSortPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void loadArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Random rnd = new Random(200 - 20);
            int r = rnd.nextInt();
            numbers[i] = r;
        }
    }

    private void selection() {
        for (int top = 0; top <= numbers.length - 2; top++) {
            swapElements(top, findMinIndex(top));
        }
    }

    private int findMinIndex(int startAt) {
        int minIndex = startAt;
        for (int index = startAt + 1; index <= numbers.length - 1; index++) {
            if (numbers[index] < numbers[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }

    private void swapElements(int index1, int index2) {
        int tmp = numbers[index1];
        numbers[index1] = numbers[index2];
        numbers[index2] = tmp;
    }

    private void drawPass(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            int height = numbers[i];
            g.setColor(RED);
            g.drawRect(x, 250 - height, 1, height);
            x = x + 10;
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent() {
        if (numbers == null) {
            loadArray();
            drawPass();

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 613, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 235, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        paintComponent();
        selection();
        repaint();
    }                                 

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is that I can't call my drawPass in paintComponent becuase drawPass needs to have a graphics object, but paintComponent doesn't have any parameters.

Sure it does it receives a `Graphics` object. You did not override the paintComponent(...) method properly in your class.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and a `working` example. Or you can search the forum using "paintComponent". You will find thousands of examples of custom painting.

Also, you should `never` attempt to invoke the paintComponent(...) method directly.

Comment: [paintComponent documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics))

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading through that now. That looks like it fixed the errors.

Answer (score 0):

if you write @override over your paintComponent method, you will figure out that paintComponent has graphics parameter

;)